# Loopers, Handlers and Threads

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm wishing to pass a byte array from the main thread of a application (MainActivity) to a "working thread" so that I can do whatever I wanna do in the working thread without blocking the UI (Main Thread).
So I read about Looper and Handler but I didn't understood it because I read that everything Im writing in the handler is done in the main thread, but I only want to pass arguments/data from the Main thread to the other thread.
Can someone please give me an example?

Comment: Using `Looper` and `Handler` is *very* low-level. Most developers are better served using higher-level solutions: `AsyncTask`, RxJava, `LiveData`, `JobIntentService`, etc.

Comment: @CommonsWare they are low-level, but also the simplest of everything you listed. Sometimes it is better to master simple and efficient things before moving onto complex frameworks, built upon those simple things.

Answer (score 0):

Handlers process messages and Runnable objects that are dispatched from a Looper. Newly created threads do not have a Looper by default as they are usually created to perform a specific task. If you want a thread to sit and process messages from other threads then you can create a Looper for that thread plus a handler that uses the looper

This is a very simple example and there are probably other ways of doing it:

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TestThread thread;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

    thread = new TestThread();
    thread.start();
}



public void testClick(View view) {
    // Check that handler object is assigned, as handler is initialised by the thread
    // itself after it has started running
    if(thread.handler != null) thread.handler.sendMessage(thread.handler.obtainMessage(123, new byte[12]));
}



private class TestThread extends Thread {

    Handler handler;


    @Override
    @SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
    public void run() {
        // Creates the Looper object for this thread
        Looper.prepare();

        // Default Handler constructor uses the Looper of the current thread (the Looper we just created)
        handler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                // Handle message here, running within the thread
                if((msg.what == 123) && (msg.obj != null) && (msg.obj instanceof byte[]))
                    Log.d("Test", Integer.toString(((byte[])msg.obj).length) + " byte(s) received");
            }
        };

        // Does the work of actually looping and processing messages. This will
        // not return until the thread is being terminated
        Looper.loop();
    }

}
```

Here is the activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".TestActivity">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:onClick="testClick"
    android:text="Test"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

You can also create Handlers that uses the main thread's Looper. This is done so that to your thread can send messages back to the main thread. In that instance you create your handler like this:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        // Process message within main UI thread
    }
};
```

To sum it up, Handlers execute within the thread that is running a particular Looper. So if you send a message to a handler that is using the main UI thread's Looper then the code will execute in the main UI thread. If you send the message to a Handler that has it's own Looper that runs within a different thread, then it will run within that particular thread.

[Edit] Hmmm. Reading back, my answer's still not totally clear so let me explain what's happening in the example: Here, the onCreate() method runs within the UI thread and creates another thread (we'll call it Thread2). It then starts Thread2 which creates a Looper and Handler and then sits in an infinite loop, processing messages it receives by calling Looper.loop()

When the Test button is clicked a message is sent to the Thread2 Handler. Thread2, which is doing nothing but sitting there waiting for messages, notices the new message and passes it on to the Handler which calls the overridden handleMessage() method, which writes to the log. Thread2 then resumes it's task of waiting for messages

Comment: there is a problem with this code and that is that the thread is not a new thread,
The code:
    thread = new TestThread();
    thread.start();
should be like
Thread thread;
thread = new Thread(new TestThread());
thread.start();
but than I cannot access the handler of the new thread....

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to say here. The example code clearly creates a new thread, the _new_ keyword and the fact it extends the Thread class indicate this. If you can't access the handler then it probably means your particular thread class is not an inner-class, in which case you can add the public keyword to the handler field declaration

Comment: OK, I see what you mean now. Your suggested code creates two objects, passing TestThread as a Runnable to another Thread object. You don't need to do that as you can simply extend Thread directly and save the extra object. You can't access the handler field because it belongs to the TestThread class, _not_ the Thread class. Use the code the way I wrote it. I assure you it works, I tested it before posting